# Problema com file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Estou tentando buscar dados de um processo (site do TRF) com file_get_contents e não vem nada. Quando eu colo a url no browser, vem.
Já tentei milhares de exemplos que encontrei na internet e nada.
Já tentei os métodos GET e POST e nada.
Segue meu código:

```
$url = "https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/arquivo/partes.php?proc=01303264620144019198&secao=TRF1&origem=juris";
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'proc' => '01303264620144019198',
        'secao' => 'TRF1',
        'origem' => $origem
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'=>'GET',
        'header' => array(
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
            'Connection:keep-alive',
            'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ),
        'content' => $postdata,
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*\/*;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        'request_fulluri' => True,
        'ignore_errors' => true,
    ),
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'ciphers' => 'HIGH:TLSv1.2:TLSv1.1:TLSv1.0:!SSLv3:!SSLv2',
        'disable_compression' => true
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$dadosBrutos = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: Copiei a sua url, e colei no browser e a mensagem que tive como resposta foi "Nenhuma parte encontrada para o processo pesquisado."

Comment: E nesse momento estou tentando e está dando erro na url.
Como se o trf1 tivesse bloqueado a consulta ou meu ip.

Comment: Aqui retornou uma pagina em branco,

Answer (score 0):

use uma biblioteca chamada GuzzleHttpClient. segue a documentação:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html

Exemplo de como fazer um get com ela:

```
$client = new Client([
     'verify' => false //desativa o SSL
     'User-Agent' => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
]);

    $response = $client->request('GET', '/http://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/arquivo/partes.php', [
        'query'        => ['param' => '1'],

    ]);

        echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

query: são os parâmetros get da URL: /teste?param=1

link para download com o composer:

https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle

caso não conheça, pesquise sobre  composer, sobre como instalar e usar as bibliotecas
ela vai facilitar muito a sua vida.

tem um erro também na sua url, você está passando ela completa e depois passando os parâmetros de novo embaixo.

a url deve ser assim:

$url = "https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/arquivo/partes.php

como vc está usando o http_build_query, os parâmetros vem depois.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o curl ao invés de `file_get_contents`.

Exemplo:

```
$baseUrl = 'https://processual.trf1.jus.br/consultaProcessual/arquivo/partes.php';

$url = $baseUrl . '?' . http_build_query([
  'proc'   => '01303264620144019198',
  'secao'  => 'TRF1',
  'origem' => 'juris'
]);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```